# How to get authentication imperatively in reactive Spring?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, javers

I am using Javers and need to provide the author of a commit. In order to do this, I create this class

```
  private class SimpleAuthorProvider : AuthorProvider {

    override fun provide(): String {
        return "the_author"
    }
}
```

However instead of hard coding the string, I would like to use the user who has sent the request. I am using a `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` to set the authentication. This means I need to access it using `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` which returns a Mono. As I need to essentially return a string from this, I am not sure how to access it?

I have tried to even do a hack or two e.g. `block()` or `toFuture().get()` but these both do not work.

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are new to reactive programing, don't use Webflux. It's a very complex framework, which you probably don't need -- see this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TJiTSWktLU

There is no out-of-the-box integration for Javers and Webflux. Still, Javers supports simple async programing based on CompletableFutures from Java lang. What you can do is to convert `CompletableFuture` returned by `javers.commitAsync()` to `Mono` which will made Webflux happy.

As a rule of thumb, never call `block()` on `Mono` in production code. You should register an action -- here `javers.commitAsync()` -- which will be executed when a Mono is completed using `doOnSuccess()` or `map()`, see https://www.naturalprogrammer.com/blog/16393/spring-security-get-current-user-programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help (and apologies for the late response). We've managed to get a work around done (and fwiw, I didn't decide on the reactive framework, and we intend to move away from it).